# compiling curl lib statically with static openssl (libssl.a, libcrypto.a)

Tags: curl, cmake

I am compiling curl statically with static openssl 1.1.1i
and I am getting the below errors:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
  system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_LIBRARIES) (found
  version "1.1.1i")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake:360 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  MobiControl/LinuxAgent/thirdparty/curl/CMakeLists.txt:403 (find_package)
```

My `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_subdirectory(myapp)
#I have set the openssl prebuilt static libs with includes for curl
set(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR /home/administrator/test/openssl) 
add_subdirectory(thirdparty/curl)
```

Any suggestion how to fix this?

Comment: You say that under `/home/administrator/test/openssl` you have static OpenSSL libraries. What **exact name** and **exact path** of `ssl` library in your installation?

Comment: i have put the compiled static openssl libs at /home/administrator/test/openssl/ssl/libssl.a  , /home/administrator/test/openssl/crypto/libcrypto.a, /home/administrator/openssl/include

Comment: `find_package` expect that you have **installed** OpenSSL library into the given directory. Or, at most, you have moved the **whole installation** into that directory. Knowing that, `find_package` searched specific libraries under specific subdirectories under the installation prefix (`/home/administrator/test/openssl` in your case). But you manually placed the libraries into subdirectories (`ssl`, `crypto`), which do not correspond to the installation, so `find_package` cannot find them.

Comment: You could try to move both your static libraries into `/home/administrator/test/openssl/lib`. `lib` subdirectory is usually searched. But next time do not copy separate files,  if you plan to use `find_package` for locate them. Instead, copy the whole installation directory.